# trigger compilation error(insert)

Tags: triggers, insert, compiler-errors, oracle11g

this is my code:

```
create or replace trigger th
after insert on stock
for each row
declare
    sqty number;
    rl number;
    isb number;
    rq number;
begin
    set sqty=(select stockqty from inserted);
    set rl=(select reorderlevel from inserted);
    set isb=(select isbn from inserted);
    set rq=(select reorderquantity from inserted);
go
if sqty> rl then
    delete from stock where isb=isbn;
    insert into stock values(isb,sqty,rl,rq);
end if;
end;
```

questions:

1.if a after insert trigger is used it means all this happens after inserting right?what if i want to not insert a particular data what do i do?i mean like if weight<15 dont insert like that.

2.if i have inserted multiple data how to retrieve them?does a trigger get called for each of the insert?(if its an insert trigger).

3.this is giving me a compilation error,i just am not able to find the mistake,even using a cursor is giving me an error.

```
create or replace trigger t1
after insert on stock for each row
declare
    cursor cl is select isbn,stockqty,reorderlevel,reorderquantity from stock where isbn>0;
begin
    for c2 in c1 loop
    if c2.stockqty>c2.reorderlevel then
    delete from stock where isbn=c2.isbn;
    insert into stock values(c2.isbn,c2.reorderquantity,c2.reorderlevel,c2.reorderquantity);
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

Btw i am using sql developer,weidly many of my trigger are not executing,but they are executing in oracle 8i.

Comment: Oracle triggers have to be written in PL/SQL, which does not have the "set" and "go" commands you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what you are trying to do, but your syntax is all wrong (where did you get it from?  SQL Server?).  See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374) for the correct syntax.

You wrote:

```
set sqty=(select stockqty from inserted);
```

I suspect you want to do this:

```
sqty := :new.stockqty;
```

Ditto the next 3 lines.

Then you have:

```
go
```

which is nonsense.  Just remove it.

Then you have:

```
if sqty> rl then
    delete from stock where isb=isbn;
    insert into stock values(isb,sqty,rl,rq);
end if;
```

Which appears to mean that if the inserted row's stockqty exceeds its reorderlevel then delete it and then insert it right back in again.  This makes no sense, and cannot be done using a FOR EACH ROW trigger as you will get the "table is mutating" error.

Please explain what you are trying to achieve and then we can help see if it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:
 1. You can use a [Check Constraint](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php) for that
 2. I don't understand what you mean:
if you want to find duplicated records then you can group by all fields and use

```
having count(*) >0
```

but why use a trigger ?
or maybe you mean that you want the values within the trigger ? if so, use
[:new and :old](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/trigger/new_old.html)